# Most optimal way to check for negative number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know of 2 ways to check that the input isn't a negative number, but I am wondering which one is the best to use. I'm getting familiar with python but I'm still confused as to what is the best when I have 2 options. If you see any other way please let me know as well I'm trying to learn.
Thank you so much

1st option (my prof):

```
def get_quantity():
    while True:
        try:
            quantity = int(input("Enter quantity: "))
            if quantity > 0:
                return quantity
            else:
                print("Invalid integer. Please try again.")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid integer. Please try again.")
```

2nd option (mine):

```
def get_quantity():
    while True:
        try:
            quantity = int(input("Enter quantity: "))
            neg_test = math.sqrt(quantity)
            return quantity
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid integer. Please try again.")
```

Comment: The "prof"'s code is not testing for a negative value. Attempting to calculate the square root of an integer in order to determine if it's negative is truly bizarre

Comment: What does optimal mean in this context? Shortest code, easiest code to understand, more performant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I don't like about the first version is that it has the same "block" duplicated under `else` and `except`. So my suggestion would be:

```
def get_quantity():
    while True:
        try:
            quantity = int(input("Enter quantity: "))
            if quantity > 0:
                return quantity
            raise ValueError()
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid integer. Please try again.")
```

Another option is to check, if the string is numeric before converting it to integer, thus ruling out the minus sign:

```
def get_quantity():
    while True:
        quantity = input("Enter quantity: ")
        if quantity.isnumeric():
            return int(quantity)
        print("Invalid integer. Please try again.")
```

Comment: [isdecimal seems better](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bZBBasMwEEXp1qeYpVSUYO9KwNueoLuShayMkwFZNaMxJGfJxhTaA_QIPUZPU7lyvTD-q9H8hz7z75_9TS5vYRw_Bml3Tz8PVYQaPEVRne2Vu7ABtuGMqrxWVZmktS7sP9OSF2QVhfcUw9AhkzMQE9JsIid01FmfEbeN0JkkAydsgYLYxqNy-lBAkvAtD5OSmYzlySgDB3jhAf92eHXYy2HtP1sfsaBV-hyUk3uevn6cKvAYDLxaA42BdBsdFzudWAPp3Nxc4Pj-_ZWnXw).

Answer (score 1):

I think first method is better, you are just comparing `quantity` with `0`.

In the second method an additional overhead you need to `import math` module or just `sqrt()` function from `math` module.

Also, when you give a negative number to `sqrt()` function you will get:

```
ValueError: math domain error
```

this `ValueError` will be catch-ed by the `except` block.

In Second option Every time you give a negative number or anything which is not a number `except` block will be executed.

---

In the First option if you give a negative number or zero `else` will be executed;

And if you give anything which is not a number `except` block will be executed.